# Load image from caches directory in appdlication did finish method in App delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

Im trying to load a image after splash image goes off.So i thought of adding a imageview to self.window in application did finish launching method.Im picking the image from caches directory.But its showing a blank screen before it loads the rootview controller .
How can i implement this
Here is my code to add a image to imageview and in turn add image view to self.window as sub view....

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];
    imgView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

    NSString *URLImg = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SplashIpad.png"];
    UIImage *imgAvtar = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:URLImg];
    [imgView setImage:imgAvtar];
    [self.window addSubview:imgView];
```

Please suggest me how to load a image after splash screen goes off.

Comment: are you getting image from cache?.

Comment: i just tested code as my asnwered and its working Well hope its helps you sujay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As par you logic and code you can do like this way:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[clsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"clsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];



    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];
    NSLog(@"do ==%@",documentsDirectory);

    NSString *URLImg = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.jpg"];

    NSLog(@"==%@",URLImg);
    UIImage *imgAvtar = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:URLImg];

    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
    [imgView setImage:imgAvtar];
    imgView.center=self.viewController.view.center;

   // UIImage *imgAvtar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"index.jpg"];

    [self.viewController.view addSubview:imgView];
     self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**[image: Screen Shot:-]**

**DEMO LINK:**
In demo i fetch image from NSBundal but you can use my above logic at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

http://www.sendspace.com/file/8srobj

**NOTE:-**

Insure that at the Path of `/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8886B938-3EFB-4F0C-96F9-41ACAE508F2B/Library/Caches/index.jpg` the Image with name of `index.jpg` palce in catch folder

Answer (score 0):

It may help you .Take a UIViewController and in that take an image view (Load image from cached directory) . In the appdelegate add the viewcontroller to window . Let me know if you are not getting me.